# angular select always marked invalid -- broken required directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

For some reason, no matter which option is selected the field is always marked as invalid once it has been touched.

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Select</label>
    <md-select flex
               id="mySelect"
               ng-model="myModel.mySelect"
               ng-change="myCallback()"
               placeholder="Select"
               required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'option.name'"
                   ng-value="option.id">
            {{option.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Controller:

```
.controller( 'myController', function ( $scope, $mdDialog, myModel ) {

  $scope.options = [{name: "option1", id:1},{name:"option2", id:2},{name: "option3", id:3}];
  $scope.isModified = false;

  $scope.myModel = angular.copy(myModel);

  $scope.save = function ( model ) {
    $mdDialog.hide( angular.copy( model ) );
  };


  $scope.myCallback = () => $scope.isModified = !angular.equals(myModel, $scope.myModel);
})
```

Comment: Can you please include your controller code ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I have included the controller code

Comment: You may have a version problem because I have tried your code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/YrrOay) and everything is working just fine.

Comment: Thanks @GhassenLouhaichi! what type of version issue might cause a problem like this?

Comment: That is a very hard question to answer, it could be anything, from a bug in the library to a code collision between the library and your code, I suggest upgrading your dependencies versions and trying again.